# deleted selected tableView row from mySql database

Tags: mysql, javafx, fxml

Okay so what I want to do is when you select the row, (Image below) it querys the row for the data in column 'itemTag'. This is a unique reference to that item and so I know it will only ever delete the correct item from the database.

Image:
[Tale Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlqOY.jpg)

As you can see, there is a column named itemtag. There is a remove button, code below:

```
public void deleteItem() throws SQLException{
    int selectedIndex = tableView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    String selectedItem = itemTagCol.getText();
    if(selectedIndex >= 0){
        con = handler.getConnection();
        String query1 = "DELETE FROM stock WHERE itemtag = ?";          
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);              
        pst.setString(1, selectedItem);
        pst.execute();       
        tableView1.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("ERROR:");
        alert.setHeaderText("No selection was made.");
        alert.setContentText("You have not selected an item to delete. Please try again.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the tableView:

```
private TableView<addStockMaster> tableView1;    
@FXML private TableColumn<?,?>itemIdCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<?,?> makeCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<?,?> modelCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<?,?> refCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<?,?> itemTagCol;

private ObservableList<addStockMaster> data;

private Connection con;
private PreparedStatement pst;
private DbHandlers handler;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    handler = new DbHandlers();
    tableView1.setEditable(true);
   data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   tableData();
   loadData();
}

public void tableData(){
    itemIdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemiD"));
    makeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemName"));
    modelCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemModel"));
    refCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemRef"));
    itemTagCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemTag"));

}
```

Here is the code which gets all the items just in case you need that:

```
public class addStockMaster {
private int itemiD;
private String itemName;
private String itemModel;
private String itemRef;
private String itemTag;

public addStockMaster(int itemiD, String itemName, String itemModel, String itemRef, String itemTag) {
    this.itemiD = itemiD;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemModel = itemModel;
    this.itemRef = itemRef;
    this.itemTag = itemTag;
}

public addStockMaster() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

/**
 * @return the itemiD
 */
public int getItemiD() {
    return itemiD;
}

/**
 * @param itemiD the itemiD to set
 */
public void setItemiD(int itemiD) {
    this.itemiD = itemiD;
}

/**
 * @return the itemName
 */
public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

/**
 * @param itemName the itemName to set
 */
public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

/**
 * @return the itemModel
 */
public String getItemModel() {
    return itemModel;
}

/**
 * @param itemModel the itemModel to set
 */
public void setItemModel(String itemModel) {
    this.itemModel = itemModel;
}

/**
 * @return the itemRef
 */
public String getItemRef() {
    return itemRef;
}

/**
 * @param itemRef the itemRef to set
 */
public void setItemRef(String itemRef) {
    this.itemRef = itemRef;
}

/**
 * @return the itemTag
 */
public String getItemTag() {
    return itemTag;
}

/**
 * @param itemTag the itemTag to set
 */
public void setItemTag(String itemTag) {
    this.itemTag = itemTag;
}
}
```

Any ideas how I can get it to delete the selected row data from the mySql database. I get no errors with this, it deletes the row from the tableView but not from Sql. I presume I am doing something wrong with the `String selectedItem = itemTagCol.getText();` line.

Comment: Right below your `query1` `String` do `System.out.println(selectedItem);` <- This should point out your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `itemTag`.

```
addStockMaster asm = (addStockMaster )tvMainTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
String tempItemTag = asm.getItemTag();
```